# Freezing HashWithIndifferentAccess in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to freeze a nested HashWithIndifferentAccess in Ruby and came across some unexpected behavior. Without wrapping neither the inner or outer hash with `.with_indifferent_access`, it works as expected:

```
v = { 'a' => { 'b' => 2 }.freeze }.freeze
v['a'].frozen? => true
```

Both `v_1[:a]` and `v_2[:a]` are HashWithIndifferentAccess's, but only v_1[:a] is frozen. Why is that?

```
v_1 = { 'a' => { 'b' => 2 }.with_indifferent_access.freeze }.with_indifferent_access.freeze
v_1[:a].frozen? => true
```

```
v_2 = { 'a' => { 'b' => 2 }.freeze }.with_indifferent_access.freeze
v_2[:a].frozen? => false
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we're looking at how the nested hash behaves differently between

```
v_1 = { a: { b: 2 } }.with_indifferent_access
v_2 = { a: { b: 2 }.with_indifferent_access }.with_indifferent_access
```

When you call [Hash#with_indifferent_access](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb), it creates a new `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` object; and then calls `#update` to insert all of the key/value pairs from the original hash into the new object ([ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess#update](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b609909dddca13512c2a9ae79e4792d5eadaef25/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb#L127)), which calls `#convert_values` with the nested hash:

```
def convert_value(value, options = {})
  if value.is_a? Hash
    if options[:for] == :to_hash
      value.to_hash
    else
      value.nested_under_indifferent_access
    end
    ...
```

So both `{ b: 2 }` and `{ b: 2 }.with_indifferent_access` will have `#nested_under_indifferent_access` called on them. But that’s a different method for Hash than it is for HashWithIndifferentAccess. In the core_ext file, `Hash#nested_under_indifferent_access` calls `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(self)`, but `HashWithIndifferentAccess#nested_under_indifferent_access` just returns `self`.

So `{'b' => 2}.nested_under_indifferent_access` returns a new object, but `{'b' => 2}.with_indifferent_access.nested_under_indifferent_access` doesn’t do anything to the object. Which is why if the first one is frozen, you get back a different (unfrozen by default) object, and if the second one is frozen, it stays frozen.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [implementation details](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b609909dddca13512c2a9ae79e4792d5eadaef25/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb) for `with_indifferent_access` you can see that it is actually a `dup` of the original hash. `dup`-ed hashes are not frozen. By calling `freeze` on the returned hash (from `with_indifferent_access`), you freeze it.